# Is there something similar to the component helper, but for html elements

Tags: ember.js

I want to `{{yield}}` some prebound html elements to a block so that they can be placed in the DOM, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that for raw html elements. What are the best practices here?

Something similiar to to the following

```
  {{yield (hash
    input=(component 'input' class='some-class' value=value onfocus=(action 'handleFocus') onblur=(action 'handleBlur')
  )}}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do/achieve? Maybe a bit detailed example? The answer really depends on that

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't, but one has been proposed: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0389-dynamic-tag-names.md

It is not yet implemented in Ember.js, however there is an addon with some limitations that can be used today:

https://github.com/tildeio/ember-element-helper

Another option is to wrap your element (or html) in a component, and yield that component.